# Issues with JFrame and JPanel Separation?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jbutton, boxlayout

I cant tell If I'm just not getting what these 2 things are but from what I gathered, the JFrame is just a big open box, So what I am trying to do is have that big box that opens will be say Red, then after that I'm making a JPanel which I assume is something that sits on top of the JFRAME, I'm trying to get this to be GRAY, So How can I get a red frame, with a gray strip on the left. I'm also trying to put these buttons vertically along the gray JPanel, and if at all possible them all to be stretched to the width of the JPanel.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Board extends JFrame implements MouseListener,ActionListener
{
    public int x1, y1, x2, y2;

    public Board()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(1200, 800);
    Container con = frame.getContentPane();
    con.setBackground(Color.RED);
    addMouseListener(this);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
    clear.addActionListener(this); 
    JButton emptyR = new JButton("Empty Rectangle");
    emptyR.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel menu = new JPanel();
    menu.setSize(200, 500);
    BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(menu, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    menu.setLayout(layout);
    menu.add(clear);
    menu.add(emptyR);
    //menu.setBackground(Color.black);
    frame.add(menu);


    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
    menuBar.add(help);
    JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
    help.add(about);
    about.addActionListener(this);
}

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt){}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt)
{
        x1 = evt.getX();
        y1= evt.getY();
}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt)
{
        x2 =evt.getX();
        y2=evt.getY();
}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{


}
}
```

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a first look, you have automatically a JFrame as soon as you extend JFrame. Board **is** a JFrame and frame is not necessary. Study the [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), especially the Swing section.

```
public class Board extends JFrame implements MouseListener,ActionListener {
    public int x1, y1, x2, y2;

    public Board() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(1200, 800);
    Container con = frame.getContentPane();
    con.setBackground(Color.RED);
    addMouseListener(this);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ...
```

should rather be:

```
public class Board extends JFrame implements MouseListener,ActionListener {
    public int x1, y1, x2, y2;

    public Board() {
       setSize(1200, 800);
       Container con = getContentPane();
       con.setBackground(Color.RED);
       addMouseListener(this);
       setVisible(true);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       ...
```

Here is a generic JSplitPane approach fresh from NetBeans:

```
public class NewJFrame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form NewJFrame1 */
    public NewJFrame1() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jSplitPane1 = new javax.swing.JSplitPane();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jSplitPane1.setBorder(null);
        jSplitPane1.setDividerLocation(100);
        jSplitPane1.setDividerSize(1);
        jSplitPane1.setEnabled(false);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jSplitPane1.setLeftComponent(jPanel1);

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 299, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jSplitPane1.setRightComponent(jPanel2);

        getContentPane().add(jSplitPane1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JSplitPane jSplitPane1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

You should configure the setDividerLocation(n) to be 1/3 of your JFrame width. The jSplitPane1.setEnabled(false) makes the division fixed.

Comment: Okay so I made those changed but I am still running into the issue, When I run it with the jpanel not added it is red which is what the frame is, then if I add the menu aka jpanel it turns gray! any ideas? thanks for the other tip by the way.

Comment: After con.setBackground(Color.RED); add con.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); for example. This will give your ContentPane a FlowLayout. I do not know exactly what you are trying to do. Read http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html#sizealignment

Comment: Im trying to get just a big rectangle, the right 3/4ths will be red and the left 1/4th will be gray with vertically aligned buttons.

Comment: For this you will need two panels. One for the buttons and one for your content. Add them to your ContentPane. If the layout of your ContentPane is BoxLayout-Line, the panels will be 1/2 and 1/2. So if you need 1/4 and 3/4 use GridBagLayout.

Comment: The easiest way to deal with the GridBagLayout is the Customizer of Netbeans. Do study the tutorials before and make sure you understand the simpler layouts before you start using NB.

Comment: You could also use a JSplitPane with Horizontal split and set the dividerLocation to 1/3 of the width of your JFrame. That will be even easier for starters than GridBagLayout.